# failed to fetch data from google status in "login with google plus"

Tags: android

while implementing google login in one of my andorid apps...getting this error  continuosly 
Failed to fetch google data (status code= DEVELOPER_ERROR,resolution=null)

already implemented credentails file of o-auth client with SHA-1 key